# organize e-mail with gnus

Tags: gnus, email

**How am I supposed to organize my daily mail with Gnus?**
Where to put my old mail (without deleting it) and stay in touch with all those old or incoming TODOs and topics?

### Background:

I already got a working Gnus configuration. I can see and reply to email.
I could not yet find an article about: how to actually work with Gnus.
Gnus does not (easily) seem to support moving mails to another folder(?)

#### How do I work until now:

- until now I am using Claws-mail.
- I receive mail daily. This mail need to be read and after that, I use this mail in my Inbox as an TODO item. This is not the best approach, but it works.
- When I finished the TODO, or the mail is just an information, I stuff this mail into a subfolder (I have nearly 120 of them, all with different topic).
- From time to time I need to look up some information from old mails (even from 3 years old mails). The information is stored in excel sheets, word documents, Zip-archives, PDFs, text files, web links, or just the mails body. I then navigate to the folder and see the mail at once or I search this folder
- what is not working with claws:

  - claws-mail does not support searching an entire folder subtree (this would be nice to have)
  - clwas-mail does not support searching in archives, PDFs strange document formats (I do not care about this)

#### What would I like to be able to do:

- I do not need to have the same workflow in Gnus, but I need to find *all* topic related information from mails fast.
- When talking about finding mails: not always the mail subject is useful. Sometimes the date, when the mail arrived, has to be taken into account.

#### Remarks:

- It is too time consuming to retype everything into some sort of database and imho sometimes not possible. So I would like to use the information already stored in those emails.
- I do not care if I need to reorganize the exiting mail folder tree.
- This question is *not* about org-mode, but I most probably will use that, too. (its the initial reason, why I would like to switch)
- I liked the idea of mu4e and notmuch, but they do not support s/mime (and X-Mail-Headers) properly, so I can't use them.

Comment: As phrased, this question is going to attract open-ended and opinion-oriented answers. Could you please rephrase to make it more discrete?

Comment: I agree with Dan: it's a good question, but it is too wide. You might start a discussion on the Gnus mailing list instead.

Comment: see https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org